# Could not load type 'System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeySecurity' from assembly 'mscorlib

Tags: c#, .net, github, .net-core

I've cloned this GH repo https://github.com/microsoft/Intune-Resource-Access and trying to build on VS2022, dotnet 4.8. I am following the guide and trying to run the command

`add-IntuneKspKey "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider" "PFXEncryptionKey"`

However, I keep getting the following error

`Add-IntuneKspKey: Could not load type 'System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeySecurity' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'`